# combobox intem does not show in crystal report

Tags: c#

I am creating a simple printing application using crstal reports, C# and visual studio 2010.
On my winform I have some textboxes, comboboxes. Comboboxes are using data for fill from the XML file. On my report I created some parameters and linked with the selection of comboboxes.

When I use:  cryRpt.SetParameterValue("PAR3", cmbSome.SelectedIndex); on my report I see the 0 or 1 depending my item selection. Now I want to display, not the index but the value ie: Monday.

If I use selectedItem, selectedText or selectedValue i do not see anything on my report.

To see what happend i put another textbox on my form and linked it with the combobox selection as:

txtProe.Text = Convert.ToString(cmbSome.SelectedItem);
or
 txtProe.Text = cmbSome.Text;

In both case when I click the button I see that my selection from cmbSome is passed to it.

Does anyone knows what happens here ??!

Answer (score 0):

Try this code in the combo-box:

```
report rd = new report();

    // set database login information
    rd.SetDatabaseLogon("username", "password", @"NOHA-PC\SQLEXPRESS", "dbname");

    // write formula to pass parameters to report
    crystalReportViewer1.SelectionFormula = "{tablename.columnname} =" + comboBox1.SelectedValue;
    crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rd;
```

Comment: I am using an XML file as datasource for the comboboxes, only to populate the textboxes. 
As I said before, I can easely send the value I type into the textbox to the report - - - winform-textbox -> Parameter-report.
Also I can see if I use selectedIndex, then on report I can see the index value of the element ie:0 or 1 or 2, but I need to see the element ie : Monday/Tues...

Comment: only to populate the textboxes. - I mean comboboxes